# Main Re declaration

Tags: go

I am making different files but the directories of storing the files is same. I am getting an error main **redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at .\hello.go:5:6**

How this can be resolved. Do I need to change the name of the main method. Can't I use it within the same directory?

Comment: can you paste the command that you used

Answer (score 2):

From [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution):

> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package called the main package with all the packages it imports, transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.

So if you want multiple `main` functions you need multiple programs, each defining their own `main` package.

If you want to keep all your code in the same package, do not call your functions `main`, give them different names.